# Diagramly doesn't update after save

Tags: app.diagrams.net

When I make changes to my Diagramly diagram, I save and then exit. However, the changes don't show in my Confluence page. How do I get the revised diagram to display?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're using Internet Explorer, which presents a caching problem in older versions of the plugin. If you get the plugin updated to the latest version, you won't get this any longer.

The version with the fix was 2.7.3, for reference.